# SmartPtr and template

Tags: c++, polymorphism, smart-pointers

As we knew, In order to avoid memory leak, we had better to use SmartPtr to managing the object instead of common pointer.

In most cases, it works very well.

Now I have encountered a problem, I tried my best to describe it more simply.

I have a base class:

```
class Base;
```

I have another two classes inherited from base class:

```
class Derive1 : public Base;

class Derive2 : public Base;
```

If I use raw pointer, I can implement polymorphic easily；

```
Base *pd1 = new Derive1();

Base *pd2 = new Derive2();
```

But If I want to use `smartPtr` to implement the same thing how should I to do? For example:

```
SmartPtr<Base> pd1 = SmartPtr<Derive1>(new Derive1);
```

Is there `smartPtr` to support the transformation, or shall I need to implement a template of `smartPtr`, but If I implement the template by myself, how to avoid the code bloating，who has good advice?

If there is a template smartPtr supporting this operation, how do it accomplish this function?
as we know a base pointer can point to a derived object, but it is bad in turn!!

Comment: You didn't really implement your own `SmartPtr`, did you?

Comment: My advice: go and implement it, then use `std::shared_ptr` or some other `std::*_ptr`.

Comment: @Brian Cain yes really！I just do not to how implement a universal template to support different base class and derived class to transform,because a base class ptr can point to a derived object,but a derived class ptr can not point to a base object,I did not know how to control it!

Comment: @minicaptain, I think Brian's point was that you shouldn't implement your own, when there are `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` available.

Comment: Yes you are right,I want to know how the unique_ptr and shared_ptr to support this function?

Answer (score 4):

Destroying the object will work correctly, so long as you have a virtual destructor in `Base`:

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual ~Base();
    ...
};
```

Comment: yes,I know this,but I want to know how the smartptr to support polymorphic!

Comment: ok, the smart pointer will `delete` the object of type `Base` when the reference count reaches 0. `delete` of a type `Base` will invoke the destructor chain, which will destroy the derived type if the `Base` dtor is virtual.

Comment: I think you do not understand my question, I want to know how does a template to distinguish a base and derived object,you know a base pointer can point to a derived object, but it is bad in turn!!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the question is. The template itself doesn't know about the derived object. It contains and manages a pointer to the base class. The C++ language defines how polymorphism works for an object hierarchy. The template isn't doing anything with the hierarchy because it doesn't know about it. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about `std::shared_ptr<T>` or `unique_ptr<T>`, then yes, it will handle that case because internally it stores data of the type `T*`, in this case `Base*`. So you are fine using it that way. They wouldn't be of much use otherwise.

Comment: thanks Seth!! I also want to know how does share_ptr or unique_ptr to support this tranformation? you know  a base class ptr can point to a derived object,but a derived class ptr can not point to a base object,how to do it in a template!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to implement your own smart pointer template, use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

For example, this will work just the way you want, exploiting polymorphic behaviour.

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> sptr1{new Derive1()};
std::unique_ptr<Base> sptr2{new Derive2()};
```

That is, you can use `sptr1` & `sptr2` in the same way as:

```
Base* pd1 = new Derive1();
Base* pd2 = new Derive2();
```

When `sptr1` & `sptr2` goes out of scope then the destructor `Base::~Base()` will be called and the internal pointer to the `Base`-object will be deleted. Make `~Base()` virtual to also call `~Derive1()` and `~Derive2()` respectively, upon destruction (same as you would do without the smart pointer).

**Live example:** http://ideone.com/zVebLV

To make `sptr1` point to another derived object do like this:

```
sptr1 = sptr2; // This will destruct previous object pointed to by sptr1.
               // Will also set sptr2 = nullptr.
```

**More info about smart pointers:** [C++11 Smart Pointer Policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334886/c11-smart-pointer-policies)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you're asking 'how should this line code work?'?

```
SmartPtr<Base> pd1 = SmartPtr<Derive1>(new Derive1);
```

The best advice I have is to look at boost or similar source for `shared_ptr`. Basically it uses a templated constructor, allowing you to construct one shared pointer from another. Obviously the underlying pointer types have to be compatible...

```
template<class Y> shared_ptr( shared_ptr<Y> const & r )
: px( r.px ), pn( r.pn ) 
{
}
```

Of course, you could avoid this, by just writing this instead in the first place:-

```
SmartPtr<Base> pd1(new Derive1);
```

Comment: +1, beat me to it, I also think this is what the OP is actually asking, not assigning a `Derived` raw pointer to a `Base` smart pointer like the other answers seem to explain.